# Current month tick labels in week format and other tick labels in month/year format(Highcharts)

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

I want to create a chart with different tick label formats on x-axis
The data(x-axis labels) belonging to current month should be shown in week format and other tick labels should be shown in month format.

Please check image to get clear idea about it.
Please let me know, if the question is not properly understood.

Any help is greatly appreciated[Current month tick labels in week format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mvfb.png)

Comment: Edit: I tried formatting tick labels using xaxis.labels.formatter callback but I could format only last tick label. check fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PurvaEQ/rzn9v7um/4/ I dont want to hardcode data as shown in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fLs9j2xj/ Data provided to highcharts will be in one format say day but tick labels should be in week format for current dates of the month and other ticks can be in month format.

Comment: In the label formatter you should check if the current category month is the same the month which is now. You need to parse the category to the date and compare months - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/zkc5pmuh/

Comment: @morganfree: Thanks. I got your solution. 
But to have generic solution, I need to understand format of data and then parse it accordingly to get month out of it, right? Also, in my fiddle, last two date values are as follows - "06/25/2013", "06/25/2012" i.e. they belong to same month but not same year. So may be I have to check year also. Correct me, if am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you need to know how your data look like to be able to correctly parse date. If you want to change the labels for months for the current year, then - yes - you should also check years.

Comment: Thanks a lot @morganfree. I got  my solution.
But there is one thing that highcharts doesn't provide any solution for such scenarios. Do you agree?

Comment: This why you can pass a callback to the formatter and write your own code to parse dates.

Comment: Thanks @morganfree

Answer (score 0):

You can make two sets of data [1]by months and [2]by weeks then marge this two datasets into one. And set the labels accordingly.

Example:

```
$monthsDataset = [300,200,180];

$weeksDataset = [100,80,110,90];

//This will be the chart dataset
$dataset = array_merge($monthsDataset, $weeksDataset);

//This will be the chart label
$labels = ['Month 3','Month 2','Month 1','Week 4','Week 3','Week 2','Week 1'];
```

I think you got the idea. Let me know if you're not clear about it.